# Accelerometer input for flying game

Tags: unity, accelerometer

I'm trying to create an infinite flying game where the gameobject (a plane) keeps moving forward and at a particular height throughout the game. I want to be able to
roll and pitch the plane but not move it up/down. I added a rigid body to the plane and selected "y" position constrain. However the plane doesn't stay in the 'y' position but starts move up or down. I just have a script that translates the plane in the z direction. Not sure how to implement the mobile input and keep at the same "y" position throughout.

**Update**

Here is the code for the plane. Its very basic as I'm not sure how to use the accelerometer:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 1.0f;

void Update () {
    float tempx = Input.acceleration.x;
    float tempy = Input.acceleration.y;
    float tempz = Input.acceleration.z;
    transform.Translate(0, 0, 10); // move forward in z 
    transform.Rotate( 0,  tempy * speed, tempz * speed);
}
```

As for the freezing of the 'y' position, I'm just selecting the y constraint available in the inspector that comes along with the rigidbody.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, be sure to [read the documentation for the methods you're using](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html).

Here you'll find out that if you give `transform.Translate` three float parameters and no `Space`, it defaults to translating in local coordinates. ie. in this case, it moves along the object's Z axis, not the world's Z axis.

Once you rotate the plane, that direction might point up or down, changing the global y coordinate of the object.

Because this change is going through the `Transform`, it completely bypasses the constraints you imposed on the Rigidbody.

So, possible fixes:

- Specify `Space.World` if you want to move forward in world space, not local space

  `transform.Translate(0, 0, translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);`
- If you want to steer left/right, just not up/down, compute a desired translation in world space, then clamp-out the y:

  `var desiredTravel = transform.forward * translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;`
  `desiredTravel.y = 0f;`
  `transform.Translate(desiredTravel, Space.World);`
- Or, route all movement via the Rigidbody by setting its velocity instead of teleporting with `Transform` changes. This lets the physics engine maintain the constraints you've configured:

  `rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * translationSpeed;`